# What is the proper workflow for major changes in git?

Tags: django, git, github, workflow

I am currently working on a major overhaul to an email system within a small Django project.

As it stands, I will need to make huge modifications to almost every aspect of the system and I think it would be easier instead if I started from scratch while deleting most of the old files.

1) Should I comment out old code or overwrite it?

2) Should I delete old files or should I rename it to something unused?

3) What is common practice when it comes to major overhauls in git?

Comment: My take on the matter - You are dealing with a repository of code. Therefore, there is a history. So, if you are moving forward with major refactoring, and you are going to be left with a lot of unused code, then remove it. Block comments, and stale files that do nothing will add a convoluted, unreadable mess. If you need to refer back to older code, that is what your repository is there for, to give you that historical view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that starting from scratch might be easier, but you might consider if a more incremental approach is possible.  Unless it is a very small program, your design will probably be broken up into several sub-systems/components.  Maybe there are one or two without significant dependencies you can start with; first get them working with unit tests and then refactor the old code base to use them.  When refactoring, **delete all the old cruft** being replaced with the new logic.  As stated elsewhere, your repository should provide the history; unused or commented-out code makes your code base more confusing.

Taking the time to refactor like this might seem like a waste of time, but it will likely improve the design.  While the old code base might be a huge mess, presumably it is does work.  By refactoring it to use the new components as you develop them might reveal oversights in your design much earlier than if you just started from scratch.  It might even make it easier to think about the new design as a set of components since you're not trying to get everything working all at once.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you're sure you don't want to use your old code in the future, made a new branch and changes everything. But if you're not sure, I would recreates a repository. It will be easyer. But you can also do reverts. It's a personal choice. I would create a new repo.